# How to make text appear on hover [ the yellow background text that generally appear when we hover on any button ]

Tags: html, css, image, hover

How to make text appear on hover. [like the yellow background text that appear when we hover on "youtube" or help icon ]

```
<img src="1.jpg" class="names">
```

i would like that text to appear when we hover on this image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the title selector in html. This will display any text you put in it.

```
<img src="1.jpg" title="image 1"/>
```